# How is it possible that an item is partial published while it is in a initial workflow step using Sitecore?

Tags: c#, sitecore, sitecore6, sitecore7, sitecore-workflow

For a project i'm using Sitecore workflows. I have a strange issue with a new created comment functionality with workflows. All new comments (submitted from a form on the website by a visitor) are linked to a workflow. There are 3 workflow states:

1. Waiting for approval
2. Approved
3. Rejected

Three fields are defined in the comment template:

1. Name
2. Email
3. Message

The comment is linked to the workflow in the Comment templates standard values. However when I run a publish or full publish the comment template field "Name" and "Email" are published to the Live website while the comment is in review state "Waiting for approval". Did anyone know how this is possible and how i can fix this?

Thanks a lot.

Jordy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess would be, that your "Name" and "Email" fields are marked "shared". If so, they would not be versioned and therefore not parttake in your workflow.

Untick "shared", and mark them "Versionable".

Comment: There is one small problem. The fields Name and Email are not displayed by a not approved comment, but the items exists already in web database by a full publish. Do I forget something?

Comment: You might need to do a Cleanup Databases from Control Panel - to get rid of the values already stored in the shared field values table. If this doesn't do the trick for you, let me know. The big hammer would be to manually delete the field values from that table, to be rid of them once and for all.

Comment: Not sure why you unmarked my answer. I'll clarify something which may be confusing you - Sitecore ITEMS are never placed in a workflow - Sitecore Versions are. So whether or not your item has versions that have not been approved in a workflow, the item will still appear in your "web" database. This is also why you needed to "unshare" your fields - so they would not appear on the item itself - and therefore always be available in "web".

Comment: If you're reading this item in code, you need to follow best practices; and make sure the item has a versioncount greater than 0. This is done by first doing something like Item myItem = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem("your web item"). if (myItem.Versions.Count > 0) - only here can you proceed to Work on your item.